# Not all iframes are being replaced

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having issues replacing iframes with text about each iframe. Here's an example below:

```js
// once
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.replaceWith(`"${iframe.title}": ${iframe.src}`)
}

// twice
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.replaceWith(`"${iframe.title}": ${iframe.src}`)
}

// thrice
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.replaceWith(`"${iframe.title}": ${iframe.src}`)
}
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

As shown in the console, we begin with 7 iframes, which goes down to 3, then 1, and finally 0. Why isn't the first for-loop replacing all the iframes? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: updated the answer with adding more smooth solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to wait an iframe loaded to replace it successfully;

```js
(async()=>{



await new Promise(r=>{

// once
let count;
console.log(count = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length);
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.onload = () =>{
    count--;
    iframe.replaceWith(`"${iframe.title}": ${iframe.src}`);
    count || r();
  };
}
});

// twice
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.replaceWith(`"${iframe.title}": ${iframe.src}`)
}

// thrice
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.replaceWith(`"${iframe.title}": ${iframe.src}`)
}
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)

})();
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

You can smooth the process by hiding the iframes:

```js
(async()=>{



await new Promise(r=>{

// once
let count;
console.log(count = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length);
[...document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")].forEach(f => {
  f.style.display = 'none';
  f.parentElement.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(`"${f.title}": ${f.src}`), f);  
});
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.onload = () =>{
    count--;
    iframe.remove();
    count || r();
  };
}
});

// twice
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.replaceWith(`"${iframe.title}": ${iframe.src}`)
}

// thrice
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)
for (let iframe of document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
  iframe.replaceWith(`"${iframe.title}": ${iframe.src}`)
}
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").length)

})();
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AW8OOp2undg?si=GSgNE9ERhGMkX_o4" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```